# Why does first if statement always execute?

Tags: php, html, upload

I have this block of code which does not execute correctly, its driving me nuts!

```
private function verifyImage() {
    if (!is_null($this->uploads) && array_key_exists('image', $this->uploads)) {
        $image = $this->uploads['image'];
        $tmpPath =  $image['tmp_name'];
        if ( !empty($tmpPath) ) {
            $newName = $this->userName . "." . pathinfo($image['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, __ROOT__ . '/images/' . $newName);
            $this->image = __WEBROOT__ . '/images/' . $newName;
        }
    } elseif ( isset($this->formInput['currentImage']) ) {
        $this->image = trim($this->formInput['currentImage']);
    } elseif ( isset($this->formInput['image']) && !empty($this->formInput['image']) )  {
        $this->image = trim($this->formInput['image']);
    } else {
        $this->setError('image',"Error with image field");
    }
}
```

$this->uploads is $_FILES from html post

$this->formInput is $_POST from html post

The problem is with the hidden field 'currentImage', firebug shows it is clearly set. However the else loop at the end is what gets set. It only returns true for $_POST['currentImage'] being set if I change the code as follows:

from: `} elseif ( isset($this->formInput['currentImage']) ) {`

to: `} if ( isset($this->formInput['currentImage']) ) {`

So elseif or 'else if' returns false, but a simple if returns true?

Comment: It sounds like the first condition is true, so it's not even checking the else condition

Comment: Your first if returns true, so the elseif will never be executed.

Comment: I suggest simplifying your code to make it more readable by caching the results of the `isset` operations.

Comment: Why are you assuming that when this->formInput['currentImage'] is set then $this->uploads['image'] will be null or absent ?

Comment: I forgot to mention the else loop is what is executing, the error is being set...

Comment: It seems like the first condition is being set, but the error message is also set... So I guess the correct question is how I test if the user has selected a file in the image field or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you simply need to understand here is that anything inside `elseif` block is executed **only** when the previous `if` statement is false.

But when you change it to simple `if` statement, it only checks if the given expression inside if statement is true.

In your case, `if (!is_null($this->uploads) && array_key_exists('image', $this->uploads)) {` becomes true because in PHP, FILES is anyway set if your form has a file input(or not). That's why it never reaches the `elseif` statement next to it.

The correct way of checking if a file is uploaded or not, would be,

```
if($this->uploads['image']['error'] != 0)
{
   // If a upload is set, this will be executed

   $image = $this->uploads['image'];
    $tmpPath =  $image['tmp_name'];
    if ( !empty($tmpPath) ) {
        $newName = $this->userName . "." . pathinfo($image['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, __ROOT__ . '/images/' . $newName);
        $this->image = __WEBROOT__ . '/images/' . $newName;
    }
}
elseif ( isset($this->formInput['currentImage']) ) {
    $this->image = trim($this->formInput['currentImage']);
} elseif ( isset($this->formInput['image']) && !empty($this->formInput['image']) )  {
    $this->image = trim($this->formInput['image']);
} else {
    $this->setError('image',"Error with image field");
}
```

For more details, please visit http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

Comment: Yeah I just realized that it is always set from the comments everyone has posted, and from testing various code. Thanks for showing how to check the upload for error. I actually got it working by adding isset($this->formInput['image']) to my first if statement, but what you put is clearly the better way of testing it. I had thought the else was the only block of code running because it was being set as well; must have been from running the code more than once.

Answer (score 0):

```
// php constant UPLOAD_ERR_OK,Value: 0; There is no error, the file uploaded with success.
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
// do uploading
} else { 
// your error msg goes here.
}
```